# Scope of the rails find_by_id method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose I have a rails app with two models `Person` and `House`. Each `Person` object has a `House_id` property.

I would like to define the following method inside of my `Person` model:

```
def locate_house
  current_house_id = house.find_by_id(person)
end
```

But I am getting an undefined variable error for `house`, how can I ensure that this is within scope?

Comment: I'm really confused about what your `locate_house` is trying to do. You can just do `person.house` to get the associated house...

Comment: There's no model association in this case, 'person' only has a 'house_id' property.

Comment: Then define the relationship. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to rewrite something already built into rails. Use a belongs_to relationship:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :house
end
```

Then you can just do:

```
person.house
```

To get the associated house.

Comment: Suppose I create the Person object via JSON, and I don't use nested models, so the only thing I have to go by is `house_id`. How can I ensure that the correct house is used?

Comment: If you are populating the house_id anywhere, the relationship will hold. But be careful about accepting untrusted data from a form and assigning the id. That's a security vulnerability.

Comment: (But if the JSON is from a trusted source, then it shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: @AndrewBarinov, just realized that if the Person is the one with the house_id, it should be a belongs_to relationship, not a has_one. If the House has a person_id, then it would be a has_one. Fixed my ansewr.

Answer (score 1):

Your model--`House`--is a ruby constant that requires capitalization

```
def locate_house
  current_house_id = House.find_by_id(person)
end
```

Comment: @Andrew, Even if this is the way to go instead of defining an association (I can't imagine why), note that you are assigning a full fledged object to a variable with a name ending in `_id`. A way to easily cause headache-style bugs.

Comment: Second that "imagining" bit. Seriously. @Ben's answer will save you innumerable headaches down the line.

Answer (score 0):

House is a constant and needs a capital letter like someone else said, look at Rails Guides regarding relationships between Active Record Models. There are many possible realtionships, has many is probably what you are looking for. Since, in reality, a person can have multiple houses.